# Sufficient Conditions for Pointwise Convergence Implying $L^p$ Convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces, pointwise-convergence

I am wanting to prove that:

If $f_n$ converges to $f$ pointwise on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})$ and $\left\vert f_n\right\vert \le g$ for some $g\in \mathscr{L}^p\left( \Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P}\right)$, where $p \ge 1$. Then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left\Vert f - f_n\right\Vert_p =0$, or in other words, $f_n$ converges to $f$ in the $\mathscr{L}^p$-norm.

This question was asked here: [Pointwise convergence implies $L^p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1514956/pointwise-convergence-implies-lp)

But I don't understand how to apply Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem to get the result as they mentioned in the second answer. Also I am not too sure how the following is true:

\begin{equation}
\int \left\vert f_n - f\right\vert^pd\mathbb{P} \le \int\left\vert f_n\right\vert^pd\mathbb{P} + \int\left\vert f\right\vert^pd\mathbb{P}
\end{equation}

I know that we can apply Minkowski's inequality to obtain:

\begin{equation}
\left(\int \left\vert f_n - f\right\vert^pd\mathbb{P} \right)^\frac{1}{p} = \left\Vert f_n - f\right\Vert_p \le \left\Vert f_n\right\Vert_p + \left\Vert f\right\Vert_p = \left(\int\left\vert f_n\right\vert^pd\mathbb{P}\right)^\frac{1}{p} + \left(\int\left\vert f\right\vert^pd\mathbb{P}\right)^\frac{1}{p}
\end{equation}

I also have seen on Wikipedia, that I am to apply the Dominated Convergence to the function $h_n:=\left\vert f_n - f\right\vert^p$ which is dominated by $(2g)^p$, but I am not too sure how $h_n$ is dominated by $(2g)^p$.

Thanks in advanced,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We aim to apply the dominated convergence theorem to the sequence $(|f_n-f|^p)_n$. Clearly $|f_n-f|^p\to 0$, so that it remains to find the dominating function. Then $|f_n|\leq g$ implies $|f|\leq g$ a.e., so that 
$$
|f_n-f|^p \leq (|f_n|+|f|)^p \leq (2g)^p = 2^pg^p \in L^1
$$
holds a.e.
Now the dominated convergence theorem yields $\int |f_n-f|^p \to 0$ and consequently $\|f_n-f\|_p\to 0$.